# react setInterval does not end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I set the `setIsRunning(false)` in the else statement, it is supposed to go out `console.log('final call')`. but it keeps calling console.log('running'). anyone know what I am doing wrong here and how this can be fixed

```
  const [val, setval] = useState(0)
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId
    if (isRunning) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (val <= 100) {
          setval((t) => t + 5)
        } else {
          console.log('call')
          setIsRunning(false)
        }
        console.log('running') // This is being called continuously
      }, 50)
    } else {
      console.log('final call')
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [isRunning])
```

Once the `val` reaches 100 I want the `setTimeout` to stop, but at the same time i dont want to use `val` in my dependency. I want the interval to be cleared so that it does not run anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code

```
  const [val, setval] = useState(0);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId;
    if (isRunning) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setval((t) => {
          if (t <= 100) {
            return (t += 5);
          } else {
            setIsRunning(false);
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            return t;
          }
        });
        console.log('running'); // This is being called continuously
      }, 50);
    } else {
      console.log('final call');
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [isRunning]);
```

Comment: it does not work as expected. still keeps logging out `console.log('running')`

Comment: After use this code, did your setInterval stop or keep running forever???

Comment: still keep running forever

Comment: ok i will check again.

Comment: new code updated, let's try again

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix

```
  const [val, setval] = useState(0)
  // const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true)
  // use useRef if you dont want to react to changes in useEffect
  const isRunningRef = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId
    if (isRunning.current) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (val <= 100) {
          setval((t) => t + 5)
        } else {
          console.log('call')
          isRunning.current = false;
          // stop the interval here if needed
          clearInterval(intervalId)
        }
        console.log('running') // This is being called continuously
      }, 50)
    } 

    return () => {
       if (intervalId !== undefined) {
          // clear if only timer was set
          clearInterval(intervalId)
       }
    }

  }, []) // userRef varaibles not needed in depedency array
```

React beta docs [explain the problem](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects#extracting-non-reactive-logic-out-of-effects), but solution is provided using useEvent which is in RFC, so useRef can be used till then

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: it does not work as expected. still keeps logging out `console.log('running')`

Comment: I edited the code, with a extra check in the effect  cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in your code.

1. Don't pass state as the dependency of the useEffect.
2. Your if condition must be in the setInterval not out of it.

And as a suggestion, use Ref instead of State.

So this would work as expected:

```js
const valRef = useRef(0)
const isRunningRef = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
  let intervalId;
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (isRunningRef.current) {
      if (valRef.current <= 100) {
        valRef.current += 5;
      } else {
        console.log('call');
        isRunningRef.current = false;
      }
      console.log('running');
    } else {
      console.log('final call');
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 50)
  return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
}, [])
```